# 10th-degree Polynomial Question

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Suppose *f* is a 10th-degree polynomial of the form $x^{10}+a_9x^9+a_8x^8+...+a_1x+a_0$, where $a_0, a_1, ..., a_9$ are integers. Furthermore, suppose $f(k)=k(k+1)/2$ for every integer $1\le k\le10 $. What is the value of $f(11)$?

First, I tried to find out any patterns by plugging in $k=1,2,3$ as following:

$f(1)=1+a_9+a_8+...+a_1+a_0$

$f(2)=2^{10}+2^9a_9+2^8a_8+...+2a_1+a_0$

$f(3)=3^{10}+3^9a_9+3^8a_8+...+3a_1+a_0$

I was not able to find any patterns..I also thought if I should use linear algebra but I don't think that is the intention for the question.

Could you give any guidance or advice, please? Thank you!

Comment: *Hint:* What do you know about the polynomial $f(x) - x(x+1)/2$?

Comment: $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}=1+2+3+\cdots+k$.

Comment: I did a bit of MATLAB work and have the answer if you need something to look forward to/check your work. (disclaimer: I did no problem solving, I just made a giant matrix)

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo? For any $g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $u \ne v \in \mathbb{Z}$, it is easy to show $g(u)-g(v)$ is divisible by $u - v$. For your $f$, $f(3)-f(1) = 5$ isn't divisible by $3-1 = 2$.

Comment: So is it just 66 then? Very easy that I thought...I wonder if the coefficients exist such satisfies the given condition. Achille, there is no typo, I double-checked!

Comment: If there is no typo, then $f(x)$ doesn't exist. If you drop the requirement that coefficients are integers while keeping degree to be $10$ and leading coefficient equals to $1$, there is a unique polynomial $\frac{x(x+1)}{2} + \prod\limits_{k=1}^{10} (x-k)$ which works. For this polynomial $f(11) = 66 + 10! = 3628866$. The coefficients $a_1,a_2$ are half integers instead of integers.